# How to copy pf status between different systems

Tags: abap, dynpro

I need to copy a pf-status of a report. But the programs I want to copy from one to another are in different systems.

Is there any way like download - upload pf-status or something like that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to transport the program from one system to the other one. Mainly it depends on your authorizations in both systems and on the settings of landscape, but in case you are authorized and the systems are both in the same transport domain, you can do the following (*I do that kind of stuff every day*):

On source system

- start transaction `SE09`
- create Transport of copies, specify proper target system
- include your report there; the entry will be `R3TR PROG <name of your program>`
- release Transport of copies

On target system

- start transaction `STMS`
- go to the list of systems (little icon with Truck)
- pick the target system there
- you get the list of the transports ready for import
- click refresh and your transport should show at the bottom of the list
- point a cursor on it and trigger the transport
- if everything goes right, your entire report is now in target system

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SAPLink](http://code.google.com/p/saplink/). It does require that you install SAPLink on both ABAP systems, but after that transferring objects from one to the other is much simpler.

The other option would be to enlist the help of a Basis person, create a transport and have them import it to the target system. But generally, that is not likely to happen.